# Unpacking a zip file before packaging using BuildConfig.groovy in a grails project

Tags: maven, grails, groovy

Grails newbie - I have a java project that I am integrating into a grails application. I have a need to unpack a zip file before packaging as is being done in the pom file of the java project. The pom looks like this

```
  `<build>
       <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                   <groupId>org.abc</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>backgammon</artifactId>
                                 <version>2.3</version>
                                        <type>zip</type>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}   </outputDirectory>
                                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                     <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

I have 2 options here - to run create-pom and declare it there or be able to do the same in BuildConfig. Due to some bug in the versions I am using, the first option is not working out.

How can I do this same thing in BuildConfig.groovy?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What version of grails are you using?

Comment: Grails version 2.4.2